# Node.js won't run from cmd.exe in Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, command-line, cmd.exe, node.js

I installed Node.js from the installer on the project's main website. I checked all of the options on install to make sure it could be used correctly. However, when I go into an administrator command prompt and type in `node`, I get:

```
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I'm confused. Shouldn't node work from the command line by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that it won't run, just that it cannot find it. I assume you used the standard msi installer from here:

- http://nodejs.org/download/

yes? If so, you probably installed it in a default place, such as `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\` or `C:\Program Files\nodejs\`. In Windows Explorer, try to find these. Whichever you find, open a command window and run this (change the first command with the path to the one you found):

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\
node
```

That should work. If it worked, change your path as described here (if on Windows 7):

- [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210213041100/http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx)

Some helpful references:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874582/change-default-global-installation-directory-for-node-js-modules-in-windows
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737824/how-to-run-a-hello-js-file-in-node-js-on-windows

Comment: `64-bit = cd C:\Program files\nodejs\, 32-bit = cd C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have Node installed correctly. You can test it by simply running a commands to see what version of node is installed.

To test it, use windows command promt and type ***node -v***. It should print a version number like ***v0.12.2***
That means you have successfully installed the node.

If not you have to set the environment variable.
Edit environment variable PATH: add ***%APPDATA%\npm*** to the front of the PATH.